# Windows UI Automation. How to automate windows explorer scroll bar?

Tags: c#, automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using the windows UI automation framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Automation(v=vs.110).aspx

The issue I am running into is that the UI automation framework provided by Microsoft is seemingly blind to some of windows explorer. I can find the root AutomationElement "Scroll Bar"
however I cannot find its subcomponents i.e. button, position, etc. This smells because obviously a lot of WPF applications would use the windows explorer to select files and thus Microsoft would treat this as a major bug in its framework. So I must be doing something wrong?

[image]

The below code demonstrates what I am doing. `root` is the windows explorer AutomationElement. I verified this as I can see the scroll bar item since it has an automation id. I also verified it was the right vertical scrollbar since there are two of them in the windows explorer.

```
 AutomationElement functionControl = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants |         
 TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Subtree,new 
 PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Page down"));
```

Comment: I'm think I will have to come back to this when I have time. However after sleeping on it, it is likely I will have to use the raw view walker. I also re-implemented this using the Value pattern on the one automation element I can get and the automation framework could not detect that this scroll bar implements that pattern.

Comment: Also since I am not testing this dialog... I give up and will find an alternate route. I suggest the same for all others who find themselves in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

What are you actually trying to do? If you're attempting to scroll down, you shouldn't do it by actually finding a the down/up button, but rather by requesting a ScrollPattern from the scroll bar itself, and then calling ScrollVertical/ScrollHortizontal/SetScrollPercent -- whichever you prefer.